# Issues with Xamarin vertical slider

Tags: xamarin.android, slider, orientation, renderer

I tried to create a vertical Slider with following code, but Maximum and Minimum track colors don't seem to work on Android (no colors are visible, only thumb color is visible).

```cs
 <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

  <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <Slider 
     RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=0}"
     RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=0}"
     RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Height,Factor=0.15,Constant=0}" 
     RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"

     ThumbColor="{StaticResource DataColor}"
     MaximumTrackColor="{StaticResource ColorPrimary}"
     MinimumTrackColor="{StaticResource ColorPrimaryDark}"

     Maximum="100" Minimum="1" Margin="0,0,0,0"
     AnchorX="1" AnchorY="1" Rotation="-90"
     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>


  </RelativeLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

I have also tried to customise the slider using a CustomRenderer,

```cs
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Slider> e)
{
   base.OnElementChanged(e);
   if (e.OldElement != null || e.NewElement == null)
     return;

   view = (Slider)Element;
   Control.ProgressDrawable = Resources.GetDrawable(
   Resource.Drawable.custom_progressbar_style,
     (this.Context).Theme);

}
```

And,

```xml
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <color android:color="#0066CC"/>
  </item>
  <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
      <color android:color="#009900"/>
    </clip>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

But only progress color appears on my view, the background doesn't seems to bet set with value #0066CC.

When I set rotation of my Slider to 0, colors are correctly set. The problem appears when rotation is different from 0.

See following pictures to understand the problem,

[Horizontal slider, working as i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Szb.png)

[Vertical slider, not working as i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trSMy.png)

EDIT : Adding some pictures with different orientations (I think it could help to understand what's wrong)

[Orientation set to -10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU2Fo.png)

[Orientation set to -45](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSLAO.png)

Comment: I couldn't  reproduce this question according the code of `xaml` you post, you can try to make sure the colors are correct.

Comment: @JessieZhang What is the problem about the xaml ? You just need to replace StaticRessources with a random color :) Colors are correct, I am pretty sure, just look the two last pictures, we can see a part of these colors, the problem is that slider seems to be truncated :/

Comment: I created a new app according to your code ,and when i set `Rotation="-90"` , that slider is not truncated.

Comment: Have you tried with an Android ? Because, for my part it only works with an iOs

Comment: Sorry so late to reply, it does work in my android device.